# How to change kendo-grid-group-panel text 'Drag a column header and drop it here to group by that column' in Angular

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I am working on angular Kendo Grid Grouping feature, where I want to change the kendo-grid-group-panel text **'Drag a column header and drop it here to group by that column'**. How to change that text?

Answer (score 0):

groupable.messages.empty (default: "Drag a column header and drop it here to group by that column")

you can set
  `groupable: { messages: { empty: "your message" } }`

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work
<kendo-grid [groupable]="{ enabled: true, emptyText: 'custom message'}">

Answer (score 0):

Write in javascript

```
kendo.ui.Groupable.prototype.options.messages.empty = "Arraste e solte uma coluna aqui para agrupar";
```